# How to write a webpack plugin to replace require function to its source code

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-plugin

Say we have a `util.js` contains functions `a` and `b`：

```js
// util.js
export function a() {
  ...
}

export function b() {
  ...
}
```

And I require them in `index.js`:

```js
// index.js
export default function main() {
  const {a, b} = require('./util');
  
  ...
  a(); // use them somewhere
  b(); 
}
```

But I want to replace the require function to its source code like this before the bundling:

```js
// replaced index.js
export default function main() {
  const a = function () {
    // ... source code from util.js
  };
  const b = function () {
    // ... source code from util.js
  };
  
  ...
  a(); // use them somewhere
  b();
}
```

I'm not that familiar with webpack plugins and hooks API.
Is this possible and if yes, how to do it?

Thanks!

One solution not that clever, do string replace directly by [`string-replace-loader`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/string-replace-loader).

Comment: Why do you wanna do that in the first place? Could you kindly explain?

Comment: @h-sifat I insert and evaluate `main` function in webpages several times through puppeteer's `await page.evaluate(pageFunction, ...)` API. And it seems that the 
`a`, `b` functions need to be defined directly inside the main function to be correct.

Comment: Oh I see. Sadly I can't help you. I've just started banging my head on the webpack docs few days ago.

Comment: @h-sifat thanks anyway!